# MH4u: Equipment for meowster hunters and stingers?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

In Monster hunter 4 ultimate surely equipment for palicoes going on quest with the hunter is useful.

Is there any benefit in equipping also the first stingers and meowster hunters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Armor doesn't have an effect on the First Stringers' self-training, and Meownster Hunters can't be equipped with armor. Only First Stringers can be equipped with armor.